# Can't import blendshapes from maya to unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, maya

Creating a mobile game that portrays a 3d model made in maya. Made some animations to the face of the character and when I import them the behavior is really weird. It doesn't matter if I use fbx or ma as the model format. The animation turns the face of the character into something that resembles broken glass moving around...
Could this have something to do with the fact that the geometry of the character is being triangulated in unity while in maya it's not? 
Everything else works like a charm. Every other animation looks great, only the ones with blendshapes are behaving strangely. 
Thanks in advance for your help...

Comment: Can you share a screen grab of your Maya outliner? Please have your blendshape and the destination mesh selected, so we can see which is which in the outliner hierarchy

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com, another fitting site of the Stack Exchange network http://stackexchange.com/sites or Unity Answers http://answers.unity3d.com

Comment: Thanks for your help... It took a few tries but it's working now... I don't know what was done differently this time by the animator. It's working.

Comment: http://cgcookie.com/unity/2014/01/01/unity-cookie-quick-tip-using-blendshapes-unity/